# Jongo Update query is not working

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

I am new with Jongo and mongoDB.

I am trying to update my mongodb document with the new Java object but its not working. Is there any dependancy/versioning issue of jongo? I couldn't find any solution.

Here is my code

```
String query = "{userName:'"+userName+"'}";
DatabaseDetails dbDetails = collection.findOne(query).as(DatabaseDetails.class);
dbDetails.addFile("abc");
dbDetails.addFilePath("filePath");
dbDetails.addfileSize("fileZize");
//HERE IT IS NOT ALLOWING with(object) type of method
collection.update(query).with(dbDetails);
```

collection is defined as a class variable of type "MongoCollection".

PROBLEM: 
Here it is not allowing me to use "with()" method and gives error as "The method with(String) in the type Update is not applicable for the arguments (DatabaseDetails)"

I am using 0.4 version of jongo.
can anybody please help me?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example (with `MongoCollection` class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the merge() method :

```
collection.update(query).merge(dbDetails);
```

Comment: BTW 'merge' method will be renamed 'with' in next Jongo release